# Hide publishing options in hook_form_alter without unpublishing node?

Tags: 7, forms

I'm trying to create a very slimmed down node edit page for a content type. One of the things I'm doing is hiding the additional_settings section with `#access = false`.

This is what I'm using:

```
$form['additional_settings']['#access'] = FALSE;
$form['options']['status']['#default_value'] = TRUE;
```

With `#access = false`, when I save the node after editing, it set to unpublished.

I've tried using `$form_state['values']['status'] = TRUE;` in a form submission handler, but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could just convert the element to a [`value`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#val) type, that way it will be hidden from the form display but will be passed through to the submit handler as normal:

```
$form['options']['status'] = array(
  '#type' => 'value',
  '#value' => 1
);
```

You can do the same thing for the rest of the elements in that fieldset, then set the fieldset itself to a `container` type and remove the title:

```
$form['options']['#type'] = 'container';
$form['options']['#title'] = '';
```

Comment: This is basically what I ended up doing. Setting options->status->type to 'value' made my form work properly even with my original method of hiding everything.